# Problem with script written in mac when running in windows

Tags: python, windows

My supervisor gave me a script to run for my Master's dissertation and he wrote it using MAC.
I get this error:

```py
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-1c59bfcd43d0> in <module>
     21                  #Add subfolder name to key Class
     22                 file_class=os.path.join(subdir,file)
---> 23                 print (file_class.split('/')[2])
     24 
     25                # dict1['Class'].append(file_class.split("\")[2])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Basically, I'm using the '/ 'to separate the GO term from the pathname and use this as an entry for the final dictionary.
Could anyone help me convert this on a language my windows understands?
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What is the content of `file_class`?

Comment: Use '\\' as path separator under Windows or use `os.path.basename` and `os.path.dirname` to construct what you need.